# Moment js not converting properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

So I'm trying to convert `Date.now` function with `moment js` and it still can't be converted.

This is declaration in html:

```
<p class="text-muted small mb-0">
     {{comments.postedAt | moment}}
</p>
```

Filters:

```
filters: {
    moment: function(postedAt) {
        return moment(postedAt).fromNow();
}
```

This is the part when I try to send it to database:

```
let comm = {
                newComment: this.newComment,
                postID: this.$route.params.id,
                postedAt: Date.now(),
            }
```

And as a result I'm still getting Date.now value (something like this: `1629462759977`)

Comment: You're sending `Date.now()` to the server and not converting it using moment.js at all...?

Comment: i did not understand what is filters for, but looks like code is working as expected. If you need to display in a specific way, always use format function  else, moment is going to written javaacript date object.

Comment: `This is the part when I try to send it to database` ← That is showing `Date.now()` which is a javascript date object. What is your problem exactly? Is it that it is not displaying correctly through your filter *or* is the server side not receiving the expected value? I see no reason why the UI should display the wrong value unless the filter is being ignored. I also see that receiving the date server side is correct as well, it would be a number as that is how a javascript Date would be serialized by default.

Comment: If you want the server to receive the Date instance formatted as a ISO8601 string then you should call [toIsoString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString). Example: `postedAt: Date.now().toIsoString()`

Comment: @Terry yes but I'm trying to convert it on the client, but it's still not converted...

Comment: @Igor I want to convert it after the fetch exactly with the line: `{{comments.postedAt | moment}}` but I'm still getting number value... I want to be display for example like this: `2 minutes ago`

Comment: Filter does not mutate your data: it only changes it when displaying it. If you want to mutate the actual value of `comments.postedAt`, you should probably do it either after you fetched the data, or before dispatching it to the server. You seem to have a misunderstanding of how `filters` work in Vue.

Comment: Okay well, but even when I display my data it's not being displayed on a way I want, the value is still the same generated number from `Date.now()`. It seems that function from `filters` doesn't work properly.

Comment: This is how it looks like: https://ibb.co/PjGPjgh
I want it to be displayed on the other way.